# Eclipselink: Modifications to entity PrePersist/PreUpdate are lost after reconnection to database

Tags: eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I have to entities with a one to many relationship between them. When I'm persisting Entity A I use PrePersist and PreUpdate to change values and create entities on Entity B and related them to A.

Everything works fine while the Entity Manager is open. If I close it and re-open it, Entity A "forgets" about Entity B. Entity B entries are still there, but the link between them is lost.

Here's the pseudo code:

```
@PrePersist
@PreUpdate
void onCreate(EntityA a){
  EntityB b = new EntityB();
  persist b;
  a.getBList().add(b);
}
```

When checked a.getBList() size is 1 after creation.

When I close the entity manager and open it again a.getBList() size is 0, but the EnitiyB are still there. Is like BList is never persisted to the actual database.

Any ideas?

**Note:** This is an oversimplified example. You can find the actual code [here](https://github.com/javydreamercsw/validation-manager/blob/new-feature-trace-matrix2/VM-Core/src/main/java/com/validation/manager/core/api/history/VersionListener.java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is based to given pseudo code.

One possible reason is that implementation does not support this approach. Specification does not require support for modifying relationships in lifecycle callback method (JPA 2 Specification, 3.5):

> In  general, the  lifecycle  method  of  a  portable  application 
>   should  not  invoke EntityManager or Query operations, access other
>   entity instances, or modify relationships within the same  persistence
>   context. [43] A  lifecycle  callback  method  may  modify  the
>   non-relationship state of the entity on which it is invoked.

Also this issue can rise if `blist` is non-owning side of the bidirectional relationship. If that is the case then owning side in EntityB should also be set.

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue on my side. Had the join column marked as insertable = false, updatable = false. Still the callback methods were not the answer I was hoping for.

For anyone else that gets to this question here's what I have learned so far:

- The call back methods (@PrePersist, @PreUpdate, etc.) don't allow to modify the original object. Any changes need to be done in by other means prior to persist.